# How to package large framework in Typescript with Webpack

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I am trying to create a framework in TypeScript and bundle it all with Webpack.

The issue I am having is that I am not sure what the "entry point" should be and when the entry point is set to all files, only the last built file is exposed to the browser.

And when a single entry point is set, None of the dependent classes are exposed (aka, only the entry point class is exposed).

**Detail:**

My TypeScript framework is rather large, at the moment, it's a little over 140 modules, but will grow to over a thousand after it is finished.

Each module under "bean" contains one exported class and a few import statements (imported classes from other modules in the framework)

my folder structure currently consists of:

```
+---src
|   +---API
|   +---bean
|   |   +---base
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---categoryscheme
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---codelist
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---conceptscheme
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---constraint
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---datastructure
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---hierarchicalcodelist
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---metadatastructure
|   |   |   \---impl
|   |   +---organisation
|   |   |   \---Impl
|   |   +---reference
|   |   \---structuremap
|   |       \---impl
|   +---enums
|   +---typings
|   \---util
```

Where each impl contains a exported class and parent folders contain the interfaces.

My first issue is that this framework is not an app, or a single file libary, it is designed for people to do things like:

```
var f = new CodeListBeanImpl();
```

or whatever class they pick.

Without getting into too much detail, the reason for these files is that there is a defined Hierarchy of structures.

For example, the class 'CodelistBeanImpl' in the folder codelist/impl has the following hierarchy:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GrLw.png)

Each file is spread out over many different locations 
within the core folder.

So, without a clear "entry point" to the framework I am unable to get webpack to simply bundle all modules into a single file and have it available to be called by the browser.

here is my webpack config:

```
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");
let list = glob.sync("./src/**/*.ts");
module.exports = {
    entry: list,
    devtool: 'source-eval-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules/
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: "development",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
        modules: ["./node_modules", "./src"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CircularDependencyPlugin({
            failOnError: true,
            cwd: process.cwd(),
        }),
],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        libraryTarget: "window",
        library: "IMJS",
    }
};
```

Now, as you can see, I want ALL modules to be packed, so my entry point is EVERY file, to make sure all modules and classes are packed.

here is the output of webpack:

```
[./src/API/IM.ts] 2.74 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/AnnotableBeanImpl.ts] 5.93 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/AnnotationBeanImpl.ts] 5.5 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/BeanImpl.ts] 3.52 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/ComponentBeanImpl.ts] 5.44 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/DataMetricsBeanImpl.ts] 3.22 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/IdentifiableBeanImpl.ts] 6.67 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/ItemBeanImpl.ts] 1.15 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/ItemSchemeBeanImpl.ts] 6.36 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/JsonBeanImpl.ts] 6.34 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/MaintainableBeanImpl.ts] 9.27 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/MetricsBeanImpl.ts] 2.03 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/NameableBeanImpl.ts] 6.97 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/bean/base/impl/PseudoHierarchyItemImpl.ts] 2.53 KiB {main} [built]
    + 181 hidden modules
```

Looking good so far...

However, when I do this. and run the "bundle.js" file in a browser, the only thing IMJS (the library name i decided to use) is the LAST built file:
[image of chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZjRr.png)

So i try to do a single "entry point" as a test to see if i can get anything other than one file.

I change `entry:  list,` to `entry:  "./src/bean/codelist/impl/CodelistBeanImpl.ts",`

and build it again, this time, only a small set of files are built:
[Webpack output of single entry point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V52W.png)

However, when I go to the Chrome console, the only class avalible to me is the one 'CodelistBeanImpl', none of it's super classes, so I can do:

```
var f = new IMJS.CodelistBeanImpl();
```

but if i wish to, say, do an instanceof check to 'PseudoHierarchyItemSchemeImpl'
it would state 'PseudoHierarchyItemSchemeImpl' is not defined, in fact, nothing other than codelist bean is defined.

Is this even possible with webpack? or do i need to use a different packer?

just for ref, here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib":[
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to acheve what I wanted to creating a file outside of the src folder called "main.ts" and programmatically create exports for every class.

Not the best solution, so keeping open if someone has a better idea:

webpack.config.js:

```
 function createEntryPoint(){
        console.log("creating entry point...");
        const glob = require("glob");
        let typeScriptConfigFile = require("./tsconfig");
        let baseUrl = typeScriptConfigFile.compilerOptions.baseUrl;
        if(!baseUrl){
            throw new Error("Unable to find baseUrl in tsconfig");
        }
        let list = glob.sync(baseUrl+"/**/*.ts");
        const fs = require('fs');
        let num = 0;
        fs.writeFileSync('./main.ts', (function () {
            let strToReturn = "";
            for (let file of list) {
                num++;
                let fromBaseUrl = file.replace(baseUrl+"/", "");
                fromBaseUrl = fromBaseUrl.replace(".ts", "");
                strToReturn += "export * from '" + fromBaseUrl + "'; \n";
            }
            return strToReturn;
        }()));

        console.log("Entry point created: " +num + " modules exported");
    }
    createEntryPoint();
```

and the entry point is:

```
entry: "./main.ts",
```